# Trying to create a POST request but getting No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-post, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to do something similar to [Railscasts #255](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail) but I'm getting a No Route error:

In Ryan's `routes.rb` file:

```
    post "versions/:id/revert" => "versions#revert", :as => "revert_version"
```

In in the controller where he uses the route, `versions_controller.rb`

```
    link = view_context.link_to(link_name, revert_version_path(@version.next, :redo => !params[:redo]), :method => :post)
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Undid #{@version.event}. #{link}"
```

In my `routes.rb`

```
    post "/approve/:id" => "listings#approve", :as => "listing_approve"
```

and view where I use my link:

```
    <%= link_to 'Approve Content', listing_approve_path(@listing), :method => :post %>
```

My tests return to me a `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/approve/1"`

If I leave the method as a GET everything works..  Using rails 3.1.0rc5.  Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong here would be very much appreciated..

EDIT: routes.rb file (the last line is set as `match` right now to work)

```
RLR::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "home#index"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  devise_for :users

  match '/user' => "layouts#index", :as => :user_root

  resources :users, :only => :show
  resources :layouts, :only => [:index, :show]
  resources :listings
  resources :features
  resources :orders

  match "/preview/:id" => "listings#preview", :as => "listing_preview", :via => "get"
  match "/approve/:id" => "listings#approve", :as => "listing_approve"

end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: I've added the routes file as an edit as requested – also note that when setting it to post I added `:via => :post`

Comment: You need rails.js for this stuff to work, is it loaded in your view?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm, it looks right to my eye. The test sounds like it is generating a GET instead of a POST though, so it might be a problem with the link_to call. You've got :method => :post there, so it should be fine. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to seems to indicate that link_to will generate some javascript to make a POST call on click (and that users with javascript disabled will get a normal GET link unless you use :href="#"), so it might be because your test engine isn't running the javascript.

You can fix this by changing it to a button that submits a hidden form, but that might not be the visual representation you want.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a precedence thing - the first matching route definition in routes.rb is used, so if you have a resources route or something like that it may be matching on that first.

Comment: I just tried this by bringing the definition to the top of the routes.rb file and it still doesn't resolve it.  Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in my rails application and I solved it the same way you did by doing a via: :get on the match instead of a via: :post. I think for some reason when you send a request in the format of /something/:id it will automatically assume its a [GET] request and search for a get route. This of course will cause problems in your routes if you have it as a :POST.

If anyone has a better solution or idea as to why you cannot send a post request in the format '/something/:id' let me know please.